# Fetch all the id attribute of the form together

Tags: jquery

I have a form and and have 10 input tags in it.Each have different id attributes..I want to fetch and print all the id's at a time..can you please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/62/

```
$(':input').each(function(){
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
var ids = [];
$('.your-form input').each(function(){
    ids.push(this.id);
});
console.log(ids.join(', '));
```

Here it is working - http://jsfiddle.net/cy7wA/1/

Answer (score 2):

The nicest way to do this is with [`$.fn.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map), [`$.fn.get`](http://api.jquery.com/get) and [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
var ids = $('#form input').map(function() {
    return this.id
}).get().join(', ');
```

This will get a nice list of `ids` without any unnecessary commas or what have you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#form_id').find('input').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: there's no need to wrap `this`in a jQuery selection. you can simply do `this.id` less code and faster

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$('#myForm :input').each(function ()
{
   Console.log('ID: ' + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Or

```
$ids = $('#myform input[id]').map(function() {
  return this.id;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: you can easily use the jQuery "serialize" function to quickly grab all the elements on the form and put them into a key/value array:

```
function getVals() 
{
    var myform = document.getElementById("formfoo");
    var mydata = myform.serialize();
    var myhtml = "";
    for ( key in mydata )
    {
        myhtml += "KEY IS: " + key + " VAL IS: " + mydata[key] + "<br />";
    }
    document.getElementById("mytestdiv").innerHTML = myhtml;
    return true;
}
```

It's a bit more code than the other examples, but I like having a single object to work with.

Comment: Note, of course, that this *doesn't* get the `id` values, which is what the OP was seeking.

Comment: The id values for each element will be the keys in the hash

Comment: No, the `name` values will be.

Comment: AH, crap...you're right.  I usually make my name/id values the same for input elements, which is why it works for me.  Thanks for the info.